# Disable SSR while serving application locally in Angular 17

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I'm using Nx with Angular. I've run the `@nx/application - setup-ssr` generator which created all the necessary files for SSR. Before it used to add separate executors for serving an application with SSR such as `serve-ssr`, but no new executors were added to `project.json` as seen here:

```
{
  "name": "public",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "app",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/public/src",
  "tags": [],
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/public",
        "index": "apps/public/src/index.html",
        "browser": "apps/public/src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
        "tsConfig": "apps/public/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "assets",
            "output": "assets"
          },
          "apps/public/src/favicon.ico",
          "apps/public/src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": ["apps/public/src/styles.scss"],
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": ["styles", "libs/stylekit/src/lib"]
        },
        "scripts": [],
        "server": "apps/public/src/main.server.ts",
        "prerender": true,
        "ssr": {
          "entry": "apps/public/server.ts"
        }
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "500kb",
              "maximumError": "1mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "2kb",
              "maximumError": "4kb"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "public:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "public:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "executor": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "public:build"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nx/eslint:lint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/public/**/*.ts", "apps/public/**/*.html"]
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nx/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/public/jest.config.ts"
      }
    },
    "serve-static": {
      "executor": "@nx/web:file-server",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "public:build"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which means that SSR is enabled by default whenever you serve the app now since v17, which is horrendous because for every change you make now the app takes 10+ seconds to reload despite using Vite for the development server.

I've been reading through the new (and old) SSR docs as well as trying to find Github issues mentioning this but it says nothing about disabling or enabling SSR while serving the app, or allowing you to serve the app using a separate executor.

I'm really confused regarding this as it feels like a huge step backwards. How do I disable SSR in development?

Comment: I have a query, if we call API in angular v17 using HttpClient, will the API be called on the server side or the client side?
I have experience in Next.js and am completely new to angular so confused about this.
Thanks

Comment: not only that, but how are you supposed to use localStorage if the app is running in ssr mode by default locally? I kept running into an issue where my server side provider for localStorage was being used instead of my local one and it kept breaking.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh You should check for browser platform if using localstorage, window or document references.

Comment: @BhaveshKumarSharma It's called on server and cached, and then on client it's rehydrated. So no extra calls are made. Only GET requests are cached by default but you can configure POST requests to be cached too if using GraphQL for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SSR is enabled whenever "ssr" or "prerender" are truthy your config.

The solution for you would be to set it to `false` in the `development` configuration :

```
        "development": {
          "optimization": false,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "ssr": false, // here
          "prerender": false // and here
        }
```

Comment: Aha.. and where is this mentioned in the docs?

Comment: I probably had that info from the team directly (can't find the source).  Do you mind opening an issue on the CLI repo ? Asking for improvements on the docs! They've just been rewritten and need some slight improvements :)

Comment: I'll see if I can find the time. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler <17 I could conditionally serve via ssr or browser in server.ts or do whatever preprocessing in there. Is that no longer the case?

Answer (score -3):

If you want to just disable server side rendering and disable standalone mode in order to merge component use

`ng new your-project-name --no-standalone --routing --ssr=false`

example my project name is `todo-app`

`ng new todo-app --no-standalone --routing --ssr=false`