Angular build hangs without errors in DevOps pipeline
I have an Angular application, that is currently running without problems with Angular 13. Local build and deployment during DevOps YAML pipeline work well. We use an Npm@1 task to run "npm run build" (it's simply ng build) for our application here.
Now I've upgraded my application to Angular 17. On my local environment "npm run build" works fine without errors and the application is running. But during deployment with my DevOps pipeline I have problems. The build does either nothing (with Npm@1 task) or it seems to finish (with script task), but does not jump to the next pipeline step.
What did I try until now:
First I've used the same pipeline code like before with the Npm@1 task. Result: I see a black screen inside Devops and no output
      - task: Npm@1
        displayName: Build Angular Client
        inputs:
          command: custom
          workingDir: 'my directory'
          customCommand: 'run build'

At the moment I do my "npm run build" with a script task. I see the output (all generated bundles and so on), I see "Build at " like on my local machine. But the pipeline doesn't finish this script task and does not go to the next one. I also installed Angular CLI, Typescript and NodeJS before my build:
      - task: UseNode@1
        displayName: Install NodeJS 20.11.1
        inputs:
          version: '20.11.1'
      
      - script: |
          npm install -g @angular/cli@17.3.5
        displayName: Install Angular CLI 17.3.5

      - script: |
          npm install -g typescript@5.4.5
        displayName: Install Typescript 5.4.5

      - script: |
          npm ci
        displayName: Install Packages for App
        workingDirectory: 'my directory'

      - script: |
          npm run build
        env:
          NODE_OPTIONS: '--max-old-space-size=4096'
        displayName: Build App
        workingDirectory: 'my directory'


When I run the generated cmd File on the agent server, the Angular Build runs without problems.
What I recognized: The order of the output from "npm run build" is different on my local machine and on DevOps. It seems to be a little bit mixed up on DevOps:
Local machine:
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
- Copying assets...
√ Copying assets complete.
- Generating index html...
- Generating index html...
1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  .k-input-label:dir(rtl) -> Unknown pseudo-class :dir
√ Index html generation complete.

Initial chunk files
...
Lazy chunk files
... (many lazy chunk files)
Build at: 2024-05-08T06:55:22.000Z - Hash: eeeb7d737af11c89 - Time: 280211ms

Warning: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 1.00 MB was not met by 4.49 MB with a total of 5.49 MB.

DevOps:
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.
- Copying assets...
√ Copying assets complete.
- Generating index html...
- Generating index html...
1 rules skipped due to selector errors:
  .k-input-label:dir(rtl) -> Unknown pseudo-class :dir
√ Index html generation complete.

Initial chunk files
...
Lazy chunk files
... (only 4 lazy chunk files)

Warning: bundle initial exceeded maximum budget. Budget 1.00 MB was not met by 4.49 MB with a total of 5.49 MB.

... (the rest of the lazy chunk files)

Build at: 2024-05-08T06:55:22.000Z - Hash: eeeb7d737af11c89 - Time: 280211ms

I've also tried different versions of Angular CLI, Typescript, NodeJS with global install and without. And also we tried to set more space with NODE_OPTIONS.
Here is my code from my Angular project:
My ts.config File in Angular 17:
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jquery",
      "node"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}

My package.json:
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "concurrently --kill-others \"ng serve\" \"npm run prettier-watch\"",
    "build": "ng build",
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/localize": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.5",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "~17.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-indicators": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-utils": "~15.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "~1.7.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "~1.19.0",
    "@progress/kendo-font-icons": "~2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "~1.3.1",
    "@progress/kendo-svg-icons": "~2.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "~7.2.0",
    "@ungap/structured-clone": "^0.3.4",
    "ajv": "~8.8.2",
    "angular-i18next": "~17.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.4.1",
    "concurrently": "~7.2.1",
    "dompurify": "^2.3.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.0",
    "i18next": "~23.11.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "~1.3.2",
    "jquery": "~3.6.0",
    "jquery-param": "~1.2.3",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "loglevel": "~1.8.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "~2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.5",
    "@angular/elements": "^17.3.5",
    "@babel/core": "~7.24.3",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "~1.1.18",
    "@types/dompurify": "^2.3.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/jquery": "~3.5.13",
    "@types/jquery-param": "~1.0.2",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.0",
    "@types/lodash.isequal": "^4.5.6",
    "@types/node": "~12.11.1",
    "@types/ungap__structured-clone": "~0.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~7.7.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~7.7.1",
    "@webcomponents/custom-elements": "~1.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "~9.1.3",
    "eslint": "~8.56.0",
    "fast-xml-parser": "^4.2.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "onchange": "~7.1.0",
    "playwright": "~1.25.2",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "wait-on": "^7.2.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.10.2"
  }
}

And my Angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "less"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "...",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js"
            },
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "lodash.isequal",
              "leaflet",
              "dompurify"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "less",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "serviceworker",
                "output": "./"
              },
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "src/styles/bootstrap/_index.less",
              "src/styles/kendo/_index.scss",
              "src/styles/.../_index.less",
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/@progress/kendo-font-icons/dist/index.css"
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "src/styles/global"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery-param/jquery-param.min.js",
              "src/assets/signalr/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js",
              "src/assets/signalr/hubs.js",
              "src/assets/pdfforms/pdfform.js",
              "src/assets/pdfforms/minipdf.js",
              "src/assets/pdfforms/pako.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "10mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "bundles",
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true,
              "outputHashing": "none"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          ...
        },

      }
    }
  }
}


My extra-webpack.config.js
const { readdirSync, readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const config = require('./angular.json');

const angularDir = path.resolve(__dirname, config.projects.MyApp.architect.build.options.outputPath);
const swDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "serviceworker/");
const swTemplatePath = path.resolve(swDir, "sw-constants-template.js");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      apply: (compiler) => {
        compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap("Generate sw-constants.js", () => {
          const swTemplate = readFileSync(swTemplatePath, "utf8");
          const files = readdirSync(angularDir);
          writeFileSync(
            path.resolve(swDir, "sw-constants.js"),
            swTemplate
              .replace(/common\..+\.js/g, files.find(file => /common\..+\.js$/.test(file)) ?? "common.js")
              .replace(/main\..+\.js/g, files.find(file => /main\..+\.js$/.test(file)) ?? "main.js")
              .replace(/scripts\..+\.js/g, files.find(file => /scripts\..+\.js$/.test(file)) ?? "scripts.js")
              .replace(/polyfills\..+\.js/g, files.find(file => /polyfills\..+\.js$/.test(file)) ?? "polyfills.js")
              .replace(/runtime\..+\.js/g, files.find(file => /runtime\..+\.js$/.test(file)) ?? "runtime.js")
              .replace(/op\..+\.js/g, files.find(file => /op\..+\.js$/.test(file)) ?? "op.js")
              .replace(/spv\..+\.js/g, files.find(file => /spv\..+\.js$/.test(file)) ?? "spv.js")
              .replace(/styles\..+\.css/g, files.find(file => /styles\..+\.css$/.test(file)) ?? "styles.css"),
            "utf-8"
          );
        })
      }
    }
  ]
};


Do you have any ideas what's going wrong here?

I don't think you need to install cli and TS globally. Also, maybe add IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT 1 after the build command (in the same script), might throw error if there is any. Do you use the same OS locally as on CI?

OS local: Windows Server 2019 10.0.17763

@Bojan Kogoj OS local: Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0.17763, OS agent server: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0.17763. The exit code seems to have no effect, I've added it to the same script as npm run build. Output looks like before, and script step never ends...

@Katharina Can you try to add the command: ng analytics disable --global before the npm run build command and check if it can work ?

Try using --verbose

@KevinLu-MSFT I've added this command to my yaml (although I have cli analytics: false in my angular.json). Result: npm run build output is now in the correct order like on my local machine. But the npm run build script still never ends, no jump to the next script task...

@BojanKogoj I already checked with the --verbose flag. I get many "Module concatenation bailout" warnings, but I get them on my local machine as well...

What kind of agent are you using? Self-hosted agent or Microsoft-hosted agent? And when you build the project on your local machine, can you check the node version and  angular cli version on your local machine?

@KevinLu-MSFT Node Version local 20.11.1, Angular CLI version local 17.3.5. I install the same versions globally before my build script in the yaml file. How can I check which agent I am using?

@Katharina You can check the pool name in YAML file. Can you  try to add the --no-progress flag to ng build command in package.json file. for example: ng build --no-progress and check if it can work? Or you can try to use the npm@0 version task to run the npm run build and check if it can work. Feel free to share the result with us.

@KevinLu-MSFT pool: name: 'Build_AgentPool' (seems to be a self-hosted one, right?). I check the --no-progress things, takes some mins...

@Katharina Yes. This is self-hosted agent. Can you try to use Microsoft-hosted agent to run the pipeline and check if it can work? refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-microsoft-hosted-agent And feel free to share the result when you using --no-progress.

@KevinLu-MSFT I've tested the things: with no-progress flag the script never ends and the order of the output is mixed again. With Npm@0 task, first i get an error during build: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory. Then I've added NODE_OPTIONS: --max_old_space_size=4096 to global yaml variables and the build runs without errors. But it still never ends up the task...

@Katharina If possible, can you try to use microsoft-hosted agent to run the pipeline and check if it can work?

@Katharina Can you add the env variable: CI: true in npm run build task and check the result?

@KevinLu-MSFT CI: true does not change anything. I will try to use a microsoft-hosted agent, but I'm not sure if this is so easy, because there are much more tasks in my pipeline, that use perhaps some specific agent settings. I will try, but this will take some time to get it to work... I will post it here if there are any news on it...

@Katharina Will wait for your update.

@KevinLu-MSFT I'm sorry, but I'm not allowed to use a Microsoft-hosted agent for my app (because of security guidelines of my customer).

@Katharina In this case, can you try to run the same commands on the local machine where the agent located? Will it work?

@KevinLu-MSFT When I run "npm run build" directly on my agent machine, I get a "JS out of memory" exception (in my pipeline yaml I set the NODE_OPTIONS flag to avoid that)

What OS are you using ? If you are using linux system, you can run the command: export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

@KevinLu-MSFT Windows Server 2019

@Katharina Run set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096 on windows machine.

@KevinLu-MSFT I've tried to set first the NODE_OPTIONS (as you mentioned) in my powershell window and then run npm run build, but I get again my "out of memory" error - even with max-old-space-size=8192. Our agent machine has a RAM size of 8192 MB

We will upgrade the RAM of our agent server to 16 GB and try again...

@KevinLu-MSFT I've tried it now with 16 GB RAM on my agent and with NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 and npm run build runs successfully without errors. I tried it also with my pipeline and there the tasks hangs again...

@Katharina What is the model of your agent? Run as service or interactive mode. You can try to create an  interactive mode agent and check if it can work.

Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops#install-the-agent to install interactive mode agent

@KevinLu-MSFT I figured out, that the "npm run build" process does not finish properly. The build is finished and I see the "Build at ..." output, but the process hangs. This happens also on my local machine and on the agent. Locally I cannot enter a new command in my command prompt then. On friday I could prevent this by typing "npm run ng analytics disable --global" before "npm run build". But this works only locally and on the agent. Today locally the process finishes without this command. But Deployment does not work. Why is npm hanging and does not finish the process?

@Katharina Do you mean that when you add the command 'npm run ng analytics disable --global' it can work on the agent too? or still have the same issue?

@KevinLu-MSFT It's a little bit strange and does not seem to have anything to do with "disable analytics": When I go to powershell and try it the first time after a deployment attempt on the agent (only npm run build), then it will not finish the process. When I try it again (npm run build), it will end the process (same powershell window or new one).

When you run the command on your local machine directly, it will show the same behavior?

@KevinLu-MSFT On my local machine, I can reproduce the issue like follows: go to another branch with another angular version. Run "npm install" in powershell window. Go back to my angular 17 branch. Run "npm install". Run "npm run build". The process will not end. When I now stop it and run "npm run build" again, the process will stop... Similar on the agent: Deploy my application to my agent. Run "npm run build" in powershell window. The process will not end. When I now stop it and run "npm run build" again, the process will stop...

@Katharina Can you try to add the "ssr": false, and "prerender": false to the development field in angular.json file? Refer to this sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77479956/20645100

@KevinLu-MSFT I found the problem: we use a custom-builder for our angular app ("builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser") which works fine for angular 13. But has problems with angular 17 in our case. When I remove it, my "npm run build" process will not hang anymore. It works now on my local machine and in my Devops pipeline ;-)))))

Thank you for your help! Now I will look for this custom-builder what is the problem there

I found the problem: we use a custom-builder for our angular app ("builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser") which works fine for angular 13. But has problems with angular 17 in our case. When I remove it and use the default builder ("@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser"), my "npm run build" process will not hang anymore. It works now on my local machine and in my Devops pipeline!
The next days there will be an update for this custom-webpack package, I hope, that this will perhaps fix the problem together with Angular 18. But for now I need to adapt my custom-webpack config or remove it and find another way to do some build steps in our project.

Fixed for me when upgrade angular 11 to 16 thanks
